# How to show that an eigenspace has a non-zero dimension if and only if Lambda is an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Really stuck on this question to the point where I cant even see the light through the trees. Already thought maybe that it if Lambda was not an eigenvalue then it would not have a basis so would have a zero dimension.

Set notation below for question 
$E_{\lambda}= $$\{v \in R^{n} :Av=\lambda v$}

Any help would be great

Comment: Well, when does the equation $Av=\lambda v$ have a nontrivial solution?

Comment: Can you think of a simple condition which is equivalent to a vector space having non-zero dimension? What does it mean in this context?

Comment: Does it have a non-trivial solution when $det(A-\lambda I) = 0$?

Comment: would it have a non-zero dimension when the solutions are linearly independent?

Comment: How are you defining an eigenvalue? As far as I'm aware this statement is taken as the definition of an eigenvalue.

Comment: That's all they gave us in the question