# Is it possible for an eigenspace to have dimension $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I don't think it is possible because that entails that only the $\mathbf 0$-vector is in the eigenspace, but $\mathbf 0$ is not an eigenvector by definition.

However, my textbook says:

> For an $n\times n$ matrix, if there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then all eigenspaces have dimension at most $1$.

which seems to imply that eigenspaces of dimension $0$ are possible.

Comment: An eigenspace must have dimension at least $1$.  Your textbook is phrasing things in a slightly unusual way.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue, then the corresponding eigenspace has dimension $0$. So all eigenspaces have dimension at most $1$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410511/how-to-show-that-an-eigenspace-has-a-non-zero-dimension-if-and-only-if-lambda-is).

Comment: Perhaps the book is arguing that the eigenspaces have dimension _at most_ 1 (since the sum over dimensions can't be larger than $n$), and since they have dimension _at least_ 1 by definition, the dimension is therefore exactly 1?

Comment: They are giving the precise conclusion that immediately follows from the hypothesis. You know that eigenvectors from different eigenvalues are linearly independent. Therefore the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is $\leq n$. If there are $n$ natural numbers with sum $\leq n$, then each is $\leq 1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How can there be an eigenspace without an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Goldname See the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410511/how-to-show-that-an-eigenspace-has-a-non-zero-dimension-if-and-only-if-lambda-is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition to any eigenvalues correspond at least one eigenvector thus for a n-by-n matrix for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ we have $1\le$ dim(eigenspace)$\le n$.

Answer (score 2):

Following the definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ if there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that:

$$Av = \lambda v.$$

The definition itself assures that, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then there must be also an eigenvector $v$. The presence of at least one eigenvector implies that the eigenspace relative of $\lambda$ has **at least** dimension equal to $1$.

You cannot define an eigenvalue without an eigenvector, and viceversa.

Comment: The question is about eigenspaces, not about eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen An eigenspace is the linear subspace generated by all the eigenvalues of a given eigenvector. You cannot separate these three concepts.

Comment: One could start by defining for _any_ scalar$~\lambda$ the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ as the subspace of vectors for which the operator acts as scalar multiplication by$~\lambda$, then eigenvectors for$~\lambda$ to be the nonzero vectors in $E_\lambda$ and finally $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue for the operator if there are any eigenvectors  for$~\lambda$, in other words for which $\dim(E_\lambda)>0$. Not everybody chooses such definitions, but doing so is perfectly coherent, and has certain advantages; see my answer.

Comment: Also, the first sentence of this answer is missing the crucial word "nonzero".

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of convention. What everybody should agree on is that $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of$~A$ means that $\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I))>0$, so the dimension of the eigenspace associated to an eigenvalue is never$~0$. However if the dimension in that formula is$~0$, so if $\lambda$ is *not* an eigenvalue, then one could still agree that $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ may be called the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ of$~A$ for (the non-eigenvalue)$~\lambda$. This may seem a bit weird, but there are many occasions where it is a convenience to be able to talk about $E_\lambda$ for any scalar$~\lambda$, without first having to ensure that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. For instance, if $A$ is a projector (so $A^2=A$) then it is always true that the whole space decomposes as $E_0\oplus E_1$, though it might happen that one of $E_0$ and $E_1$ has dimension$~0$ (namely if $A=I$ respectively $A=0$); this statement would be more complicated to make if it were forbidden to mention $E_\lambda$ unless $\lambda$ was actually an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't imply that dimension 0 is possible. You know by definition that the dimension of an eigenspace is at least 1. So if the dimension is also at most 1 it means the dimension is exactly 1. It's a classic way to show that something is equal to exactly some number. First you show that it is at least that number then that it is at most that number.